# C# - Как получить пути к ДОСТУПНЫМ файлам на дисках C,D и тд?

Tags: c#

Я пробовал это делать, но, например, на диске C программа не могла зайти в некоторые папки, так как она отказывала в доступе и все - не записывалось ничего. Мне нужно пропускать папки, которые отказали в доступе. Смысл в том, чтобы получить пути ко всем файлам, например, файлам .exe или .txt, которые находятся на диске C или D во всех каталогах и подкаталогах, и записать пути этих файлов в список List.

Comment: Добавте ваш код прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Просто проверяйте исключения, и всё.